Как удалить username бота перед реферальной ссылкой, после выбора чата?
Возможно ли удалить username бота перед ссылкой, после выбора чата: "@Bot https://t.me/Bot?start=1" - это сообщение после выбора чата. Как из него удалить все, что перед ссылкой, чтобы стало вот так: "https://t.me/Bot?start=1"?
Функция (библиотека Telebot):
def switch(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    bot_name = bot.get_me().username
    switch_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Try', switch_inline_query=ref_link.format(bot_name, message.chat.id))
    markup.add(switch_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выбрать чат", reply_markup = markup)


например,print("@Bot https://t.me/Bot?start=1"[5:]) или
print("@Bot https://t.me/Bot?start=1".replace("@Bot ", "")) или print("@Bot https://t.me/Bot?start=1"["@Bot https://t.me/Bot?start=1".find('https:'):])

Это не то, нужно удалить bot`s username при отправке сообщения в другой чат. Видимо никак, тк API так работает и ничего не поделаешь.

Решилось через обычный url:
ref_link = 'https://t.me/share/url?url=https://t.me/{}?start={}'\

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['invite'])
def inv(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    bot_name = bot.get_me().username
    switch_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Пригласить друга', url=ref_link.format(bot_name, message.chat.id))
    markup.add(switch_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выбрать чат", reply_markup = markup)

